# BigQuery pricing: query data size (cost) calculation for record columns

Tags: google-bigquery

How does BigQuery calculate the data size to process for nested columns?

I have data that I want to load into BigQuery, but I'm not certain as to the schema I should use.

The data I have has (among others) the following columns:

- `timestamp`
- `sessionId`
- `event` (a required record)
- `event.id`
- `event.details` (a nullable record)
- `event.details.type`
- `event.details.name`
- `event.attributes` (a repeated record)
- `event.attributes.key`
- `event.attributes.value`

My questions:

1. If I query only `event.id`, will the data in the other `event.*` columns also be scanned?

   SELECT event.id FROM `table_name`

The BigQuery UI shows no difference for the scanned data size of these queries on an existing table (this table has no non-repeatable nested columns).

```
SELECT attrs.name FROM `other_table_name`, UNNEST(attributes) AS attrs
SELECT attrs.name, attrs.value FROM `other_table_name`, UNNEST(attributes) AS attrs
```

2. Are both `attributes.*` columns scanned because of the UNNEST operation?

Unfortunately, the (detailed) information from Google does not answer these questions, as it does not mention nested columns with [query pricing](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing#queries), and it too vague when describing [data sizes](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing#data)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have just tested now with a public table: `bigquery-public-data.bitcoin_blockchain.transactions`. I have run the following queries:

**Query 1:**

```
SELECT
  inputs.input_script_bytes,
  inputs.input_script_string,
  inputs.input_script_string_error,
  inputs.input_sequence_number
FROM
  `bigquery-public-data.bitcoin_blockchain.transactions`,
  UNNEST(inputs) AS inputs
LIMIT
  100
```

And it returns `327 GB` processed.

**Query 2:**

```
SELECT
  inputs.input_script_bytes
FROM
  `bigquery-public-data.bitcoin_blockchain.transactions`,
  UNNEST(inputs) AS inputs
LIMIT
  100
```

And it returns `100 GB` processed.

So, answering your first question, the other columns of `event.*` should not be scanned. Regarding the second question, I see different scanned data size when run the queries. If you see difference of bytes in the [Validator](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/best-practices-costs#using_the_query_validator), notice that it is just an estimation of the number of bytes read.

Comment: Thank you. I think that the column size(s) in my dataset are too small to change the estimate. These queries are most helpful. Thank you!