# Querying tables with repeated fields: Performance considerations

Tags: google-bigquery

Assume we have a table with two dimensions (DimA & DimB) and one repeated field (Facts).

[image]

Now also consider the "flattened" version of it:

[image]

We should expect queries directed toward the first table to be generally cheaper since we are scanning fewer rows. However, from my experience, it looks like it is cheaper to direct queries on the flattened version of the table.

For example, it turns out that

```
select sum(A) from tableA, unnest(facts) where dimA = 1001
```

is more expensive than

```
select sum(A) from tableB where dimA = 1001
```

This is (at least to me) counterintuitive and was wondering why this is happening.

Answer (score 1):

The second query is cheaper than the first is because the second query select only one column where as the first query needs to unnest three column. (related but not quite the same question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53266945/3054766)

Because BigQuery store as columnar (column based), selecting less columns are sure to be cheaper. In your case, it's the trade-off between **saving the storage cost** (the first option), or the **query cost/performance** (the second option). Considering the ease of querying, I think the second option will be much more cleaner.

Comment: So, it depends if your priority is storing large number of files to save the storage usage and not query very often, you can go for the option one. But if you need to query a lot and query often, the ease of querying could be your priority. Then, you can go for the option two.

Comment: The thing is, that, when unnesting it does not scan all three columns. For example, these two queries: 

"select sum(A) from tableA, unnest(facts) where dimA = 1001"

and 

"select sum(A), sum(B) from tableA, unnest(facts) where dimA = 1001"

scan different amounts of data.